# Android: how to create N listviews?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have an application that sends a request to an API, where JSON data is returned and displayed.  Depending on the user, there will be data for multiple locations with each location being a header and having its own listview.  How would I do this in Android?  I understand the concept of a single dynamic listview, but how would I generate MULTIPLE LISTVIEWS DYNAMICALLY?

Comment: you mean listview in listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what do you mean by multiple listviews dinamically, and first of all why would you need this, but perhaps you just need an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)?

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This
>   differs from the ListView by allowing two levels: groups which can
>   individually be expanded to show its children.